# Need somebody to help us with our existing Craft web page

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Our developer has disappeared and we need some help in changing and adding a few things on our website (www.fincarosablanca.com)? Would like to have somebody in Costa Rica but it doesn't really matter.

Comment: You could post this on https://www.workwithcraft.com/ too

Answer (score 6):

Sorry to hear about your disappearing developer.

Stack Exchange as a Q&A site usually isn't the best place to find a developer, unless you'd like to post to Stack Overflow Jobs (https://stackoverflow.com/jobs).

For Craft specific developers, there are a couple of places you could look:

1. https://craftcms.com/partners
2. https://www.workwithcraft.com/
3. https://straightupcraft.com/jobs
4. The Craft Slack #jobs channel: https://craftcms.com/community#slack